# CMAKE executing GREP command leaves output variable empty

Tags: cmake, grep

I am trying to get information from file using regexp from withing a cmake file.
Here is a simple file.txt located at my home directory:

```
entry1
entry2
```

In CMake I call grep in the following way:

```
        SET(GREP_ARGS -oP \".*$\" /home/yuriy/file.txt)
        MESSAGE(STATUS ${GREP_ARGS})
        EXECUTE_PROCESS(
            COMMAND
            grep ${GREP_ARGS}
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE MODULE_MSGS
            ERROR_VARIABLE ERR)
```

However output/error variables are both empty. Moreover I am sure that the command is executed since if I change name of the file to non-existing one I got an error "No such file or directory" inside my output variable. Therefore it seems for me that the issue is in regular expression parameter passing. I have tried to wrap it with `"` but it does not help.

Calling the same command from bash gives right output on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
grep -oP ".*$" /home/yuriy/file.txt
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution. The right way of setting arguments is without `\"` symbols:

```
SET(GREP_ARGS -oP .*$ /home/yuriy/file.txt)
```

Not sure why is it so but it works.